# Python Regex how to match a substring without replace a part of that

Tags: python, regex, text, nlp, text-processing

I have the following sentence:

> sentence = "Work \nExperience \n\n First Experience..."

```
Work 
Experience 

 First Experience...
```

So, I want to remove the "\n" between Work and Experience, but at the same time I don't want remove "\n\n" after Experience.

```
Work Experience 

First Experience...
```

I've tried different solution like:

```
string = re.sub(" \n{1}[^\n]"," ",sentence)
```

but all of them remove the first character after \n (E).

Update: I managed to find the solution thanks to @Wiktor

> print(re.sub(r'\w .*?\w+', lambda x: x.group().replace('\n', ''), sentence, flags=re.S))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to make it a generic solution to remove any amount of `\n`, a newline, in between two strings, you can use

```py
import re
sentence = "Work \nExperience \n\n First Experience..."
print( re.sub(r'Work.*?Experience', lambda x: x.group().replace('\n', ''), sentence, flags=re.S) )
```

See the [Python demo](https://ideone.com/6ZBNLn). Output:

```py
Work Experience 

 First Experience...
```

The `Work.*?Experience` with `re.S` matches any substrings between (and including) `Work` and `Experience` and then the match data object (`x`) is processed upon each match when all newlines are removed usign `.replace('\n', '')` and these modified strings are returned as replacement patterns to `re.sub`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer ! What if I had a big text in which this problem is repeated not only for this case, but also for other sentences?
I've tried intuitively with:
re.sub(r'\w .*?\w', lambda x: x.group().replace('\n', ''), sentence, flags=re.S)
but obviousely it doesn't work well

Comment: @sergiozavota Start from the very beginning with requirements. What should you match start with? What should it end with?

Comment: The words are not "static", so you could have 
sentence1 = "Work \nExperience \n\n First Experience..."
sentence2 = "Sergio \nZavota \n\n Second Experience..."
sentence3 = "Wiktor \nStribiżew \n\n Third Experience..."
etc..

Comment: @sergiozavota So what is the *pattern*? What is regular here? How can we know that we need to match from `Wiktor` to `Stribiżew`?

Comment: The pattern is:
word + space + \n + word + space + \n + \n + space + words (+ means a concatenation)
This is repeated for a certain number of sentences, like I have shown above.

Comment: After understanding better your result I managed to find out the general solution.
Since Wiktor and Stribiżew (or Work and Experience) are words, I have to replace the static words with the "\w" char (the second is \w+ because the \n is attached to a word, not a single char) and make a space between the first word and the .*?:

`print(re.sub(r'\w .*?\w+', lambda x: x.group().replace('\n', ''), sentence, flags=re.S)) `

Thank you

Comment: @sergiozavota Glad you found it out. Also, you could use a word boundary rather than space: `r'\w\b.*?\w+'`